# How to detect and convert DOS/Windows end of line to UNIX end of line in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, unix

I have implemented a CSV upload in Ruby (on Rails) that works fine when the file is uploaded from a browser that runs on UNIX-like systems

However I have a file that as uploaded by a real customer contains the famous ^M as end of lines (I guess it was uploaded from Windows)

I need to detect this situation and replace the character before the file is processed

Here is the code that creates the file

```
# create the file on the server
path = File.join(directory, name)
# write the file
File.open(path, 'wb') { |f| f.write(uploadData.read) }
```

Do I need to change the "wb" to "w" and this would solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CR (^M as you say it) char is `"\r"` in Ruby (and many other languages), so if you're sure your line endings also have the LF char (Windows uses CRLF as the line ending) then you can just remove all the CRs at the ends of the lines (`$` matches at the end of a line, before the last `"\n"`):

```
uploadData.read.gsub /\r$/, ''
```

If you're not sure you're going to have the LF (eg. MacOS 9 used to use a plain CR at the end of the line) then replace any CR optionally followed by a LF with an LF:

```
uploadData.read.gsub /\r\n?/, "\n"
```